# Solving for solutions of $x(x-y)(x-z)=3$, $y(y-x)(y-z)=3$, $z(z-y)=3$ where $x,y,z\in\mathbb C$.

Tags: systems-of-equations

Consider system of equations $x(x-y)(x-z)=3$, $y(y-x)(y-z)=3$, $z(z-y)=3$ where $x,y,z\in\mathbb C$.
Then which of the following is/are True?

A. There are  different solutions.

B. sum $(x+y+z)$ in any solution is Zero.

C. No two of $x,y,z$ can be simultaneously real

D. Any solution lies on a straight line.

I tried various ways but I couldn't figure it out. According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=x%5C%2840%29x-y%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29x-z%5C%2841%29%3D3%5C%2844%29y%5C%2840%29y-x%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29y-z%5C%2841%29%3D3%5C%2844%29z%5C%2840%29z-y%5C%2841%29%3D3), there are $7$ different solutions to it.

Comment: Oof, if I put the problem through a Groebner basis calculation, it gives a degree 7 polynomial in $z$ (and it does appear that polynomial has nonzero discriminant), and then it can express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$.

Comment: On the other hand, if I change the last equation to $z(z-x)(z-y)=3$ (for symmetry with the others), then I get a simple Groebner basis of $x+y+z, y^2+yz+z^2, z^3-1$.

Comment: To follow up on @DanielSchepler's observation: the solutions of the symmetric system are the six permutations of $(x,y,z)=(1,e^{2\pi i/3},e^{4\pi i/3})$. This in particular would mean that $x+y+z=0$.